# Enable SMB sharing from command line

Tags: terminal, launchd, smb, plist, daemons

On OS X 10.8, using terminal commands, I'd like to enable SMB sharing as if I had ticked the following checkbox under `System Preferences - Sharing - File Sharing - Options`:

[image]

I've tried the following command:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist`

But despite the smb daemon seeming to be up and running, the checkbox is still unchecked, as if something is missing.

The same command works, as an example, for screen sharing (`com.apple.screensharing.plist`) and even for AFP (`com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist`), only SMB seem to suffer from this problem.

Comment: Read the small print under the Check box for SMB!

Comment: That's a different thing. When I tick the box on System Preferences I don't need to enter passwords or anything else, so there must be a way to do the same with commands without dealing with passwords.

Comment: On modern systems, it seems the `launchctl` command is all that's needed. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8463141.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution. Two commands are needed in sequence:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist EnabledServices -array disk
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who might be having this same issue with a different root cause, I found that somehow my `com.apple.smbd.plist` file had gotten corrupt.

You can check this with `cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist`.
It should appear to be plain text, but if you see a bunch of weird characters, it's probably corrupt.

I simply deleted the file [and after realizing it did not get recreated on reboot] copied my `com.apple.smbd.plist` from another Mac into `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`.  Then I checked the checkbox (or alternately, you could run `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist`), and then rebooted.

Problem solved.  Same issue, different root cause.

**Edit:** You should also verify permissions on `com.apple.smbd.plist` and `com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist`, especially if copying from a different computer.  I discovered that my `com.apple.AppleFileSharing.plist` file had `777` permission, which was causing it not to load.

Ownership should be `root:wheel`, and permissions should be `644`:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
sudo chown root:wheel /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
sudo chmod 644 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
sudo chmod 644 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

Comment: Plist has both a textual format and a binary format, and the latter is prevalent in the system. So it doesn't mean at all that the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for a new approach that would work on macOS 13 (Ventura) and use the modern `launchctl` syntax. None of the above are working for me.

I'm ***close*** with the script below.

```bash
sudo launchctl enable system/com.apple.smbd 
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist 
sudo launchctl kickstart -kp system/com.apple.smbd
```

It does turn on SMB, and the File Sharing toggle in System Settings *does* flip to the "on" position. But something isn't right with the smbd daemon permissions when invoked this way. Connections from my iOS devices fail in strange ways, certain directories can't be traversed, etc.

One significant thing I discovered is, when toggling File Sharing on via the GUI, running `pgrep -lf smbd` yields no results. Some other daemon besides `/usr/sbin/smbd` appears to be providing the service. But `sudo lsof -Pi :445` does not reveal which particular binary has the port open.

I'm hoping someone might be able to build on this and figure out the missing piece.